# BASH copy files from MTP device - can't cd to SD card

Tags: bash, mtp, copy

Have successfully mounted an MTP device on the desktop in Ubuntu and have figured out where the mount point is.

If I `cd` to `/run/user/999/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C006%5D$`

I see 'SD card'

But this is also what I see on the desktop.
How can I `cd` INSIDE the SD card to copy photos or videos?

[image]

Comment: try `cd "SD card"` or `cd SD\ card`.

Comment: Using `Files` file manager, go to `Computer`, and look in /media or /mnt. Ultimately, you'll find the path to `SD Card`, and your CD command should look something like `cd /media/your_username/SD\ Card`.

Comment: @souravc your cd command path is relative to the current directory (normally ~/), and won't get the user to the SD Card.

Comment: @heynnema you are correct. In the image above OP reached to the parent directory of SD card. My instruction was intended after that only. I should have made it clear. Thanks

Comment: @souravc Oh, now I see what the thinking was. However, that /run path is nothing you'd ever want the user to type into a cd command. See my comment  and tell me if you agree.

Comment: OP, Thanks for the suggestions. Further research suggests i should use the following  sudo apt-get install libmtp-dev mtp-tools mtpfs and then mtp-getfile to retrieve file by ID.